# Combobox default item appears selected on default

Tags: combobox

The comboboxes's default items on the dialog appear selected by default initially. No special code or properties being set that I'm aware of.

I'm expecting them to be highlighted when an item selected explicitly instead of on default.

any ideas?

This is a C# application with .net 4.0

[image]

Thanks,